# Summarize data using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I am trying to summarize my data and I am getting an error:

```
know_member2 <- cmaother %>%
  group_by(Know_member,fishers) %>%
  summarize(Gender= length(Gender)) %>%
  spread(Know_member,fishers) %>% 
  replace(., is.na(.), "0") %>%
  print(n = Inf)
```

> ```
> Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows (2, 4)
> ```

Can anybody please help me?

Comment: Please share sample data with `dput`

Comment: You have (probably) got duplicate identifiers in rows 2 and 4  ;-)  please add sample data to reproduce...

Comment: Try `cmaother %>%count(Know_member,fishers)  %>% spread(Know_member, n, fill = 0)`  I believe the `spread` used wrong column instead of 'Gender' i.e. `cmaother %>% group_by(Know_member, fishers) %>% summarise(Gender = n()) %>% spread(Know_member, Gender)`

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example in r](//stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). The link I provided, will tell you how. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and review [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and then edit the question accordingly. You need to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us some efforts. Cheers.

Comment: @Frank what about `tidyverse` in the tags instead of `dplyr` & `tidyr`? and changing the title as well.

Comment: @M-M Sure. I just added tidyr since the source of the error is the spread function, but I think tidyverse is fine instead. I think a less general title would be better -- wouldn't want people landing here from google based on that title when the question boils down to something much more specific.

Comment: @Frank @M-M The beginning of the `tidyverse` tag wiki reads: "DO NOT USE if your question relates to one or two components of the tidyverse, such as dplyr or ggplot2. Use *those* tags, and tag with `r` as well for a better response." So based on that, tagging `dplyr` and `tidyr` is appropriate and `tidyverse` isn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, the issue is using a different column in the `spread` instead of the count column.  Also, `length` can be changed to `n()` and the last step or `replace`ment of missing value with 0 by making use of the `fill` argument in `spread`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
cmaother %>%
    group_by(Know_member, fishers) %>% 
    summarise(Gender = n()) %>%  
    spread(Know_member, Gender, fill = 0)
```

It can be modified to a compact option with `count`

```
cmaother %>%
   count(Know_member,fishers) %>% 
   spread(Know_member, n, fill = 0)
```

Comment: Thanks very much the code works well that is  what I wanted .